# Can a hadoop job be paused or suspended?

Tags: hadoop

I'm using hadoop-0.20.2.

Looking at `hadoop fs`. I am able to kill or fail an individual task. Is there anyway to pause it so that the map slots are freed up for another task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  You can't suspend a job.

There isn't.  Slots are assigned for the duration of the tasks.

You can decrease the priority in the scheduler which will allow some slots to be reclaimed as tasks complete.

Comment: This is good, if sad answer :(